# Put state value to function in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, state

How I can put my *name* and *city* value from state to axios.post function in React?
It looks preety simple but I stuck on it. Please help me and post some solutions.

Regards

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class CreateClient extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'Name',
    city: 'City',
  }
  submit() {
    axios
      .post('http://localhost:4000/clients', {
        name: stateValue,
        city: stateValue,
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
  render() {
    const { name, city } = this.state
    return (
      <div className="CreateClient Wrapper">
        <form className="flex flex-column Item mt3">
          <button type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.submit}>Submit client</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CreateClient
```

Comment: You'll need to make sure the handler receives the correct `this` context in `render`: `onClick={() => this.submit()}`. Then in your `submit` method, use `this.state.name`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew! All right now.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-form-example-gm9o6